# Métricas interesantes para el sitio

Tags: discusión, data-explorer, estadísticas

Durante el beta fuimos observando diferentes estadísticas, desde [las métricas de salud del sitio en Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), pasando por infinidad de queries en SEDE y varias peleas contra la base de datos para ver cómo nos iba. Eso fue acompañado de diferentes publicaciones en meta, cada una fiel reflejo de la etapa en la que estábamos. Incluso vimos cómo el sitio fue escalando en tráfico en comparación a otras comunidades de Stack Exchange, que hoy nos coloca en [el 6to lugar en cantidad de preguntas por día](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

Pero a partir de la graduación, cambian drásticamente los privilegios y creo que es un excelente momento para volver a poner foco en observar con detenimiento cómo evoluciona el sitio.

Me pareció que un buena idea sería pedir que publiquen métricas del sitio, en respuestas separadas.

**¿Qué métricas resultan útiles para seguir el avance de SOes?**

Comment: Excelente información muchas gracias @Mariano

Comment: Estoy tremendamente compungido por mi ausencia en las estadísticas de usuarios :'(

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster estos números se logran entre todos... Y, desde ya, la idea es que quien quiera agregue otras métricas... Probablemente estés entre los primeros en puntaje medio por respuesta.

Comment: @Mariano era broma :') el aparecer en los ránkings solo beneficia a mi ego no al sitio.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Te hice [un SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/675803/usuarios-por-reputacion-pruebas).

Answer (score 12):

## Salud del sitio

[image]

- *c/ X'* indica que, de media, hay una publicación cada X minutos, aproximadamente.
- Al recargar la imagen muestra los valores actualizados cada ~5 minutos.

Comment: Para quien prefiera con el texto "cada" en vez de "c/": https://soes-stats.000webhostapp.com/salud-soes.png

Answer (score 7):

## Por países

#### [Mundial de Reputación](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/551411/mundial-de-reputacion#resultSets)

> [image]
>   * Captura al 16/5/17

Comment: Jorgesys tiene tanta reputación como todos los usuarios de Venezuela, Canada y Cuba juntos 0.o

Comment: ¿Esta gráfica significa que soy el usuario de Colombia con más reputación hasta el momento?

Comment: @Jorius sí. Significa que, entre todos los usuarios de SOes que pusieron "Colombia" como ubicación dentro de su perfil, estás primero en reputación, actualizado al domingo pasado (y yendo al enlace, podés seguir viéndolo actualizado semanalmente).

Comment: ¿No se puede que también sea de México ? (⌐■_■)

Comment: @Jorgesys con tu reputación, podrías proclamarte país independiente con el nombre que quieras 

Comment: Me acabo de fijar que, a no ser que no entienda la consulta (que todo puede ser), el ranquin no esta *normalizado*. Entendiendo como normalizado el tener en cuenta cuántos usuarios tiene un país determinado: es más fácil para España tener más reputación si tiene más usuarios... ¡no debería `Us/Pais` y `Rep/Us` usarse para calcular un factor multiplicador o divisor?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Lo que se está presentando es el total: cuánta reputación sumó en total cada país en el sitio... La media por usuario (que es *otra* métrica interesante) es justamente `Rep/Us` ni más ni menos, justamente por eso agregué la columna (y se puede ordenar así entrando al enlace publicado y haciendo click en el encabezado de la tabla)... Quizás sería más representativo presentar la *mediana* en vez de la *media*, y ahí sí opté por simplificar... Pero si interesa que agregue otro valor, lo incluyo.

Answer (score 7):

## Preguntas no respondidas por etiqueta

#### http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/42823/unanswered-questions-by-tag#resultSets

> [image]
>   * Captura al 16/5/17

Comment: Qué buen trabajo estamos haciendo en la etiqueta [tag:c++] y [tag:c] :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster lo cierto es que sí

Answer (score 6):

## Moderación

#### [Editores más prolíficos](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors#resultSets)

Editores que quedan como el editor más reciente de la publicación. Ignora las ediciones a publicaciones propias y las que tuvieron una edición subsecuente de otro usuario. El número de ediciones presentado es muy conservador respecto a la cantidad total de ediciones realizadas.

> [image]
>   * Captura al 19/5/17

Comment: ¿Esa captura es de ayer? Estoy casi seguro que llevo cerca de 500 ediciones

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro para esta métrica, sólo se están tomando a los últimos editores (yendo al enlace en SEDE se muestra que toma el campo `LastEditorUserId`). Creo que es más interesante ver las ediciones que quedan como ediciones finales. En mi caso igual, llevo más de 1500 (se ven en el perfil de cada uno). Recién edité para aclarar.

Answer (score 4):

## Votos

#### [Votos de usuarios de mayor reputación](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/670814/votos-de-usuarios-de-mayor-reputacion?TOP=500&ActivoHace=90&RepMin=200&RepMax=0&PostsMin=50&VotosMin=0&UVMin=0&DVMin=0&VRepMin=0&VRepMax=0&VdayMin=0&VdayMax=0#resultSets)

> [image]
>   * Captura al 16/5/17

#### [Votos de usuarios sin privilegio a voto](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/636845/votos-de-usuarios-no-registrados-en-el-sitio#resultSets)

Corresponde a los votos emitidos como "anónimos" (o "*post feedback*"), de usuarios no registrados o usuarios sin el privilegio para [votar positivo (15+)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) o [votar negativo (125+)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Esta métrica es sumamente importante para ver qué publicaciones están atrayendo la atención de usuarios que aún no participan activamente en el sitio, y que probablemente hayan entrado a leer una publicación en particular.

> [image]
>   * Captura al 16/5/17

- Puntaje: `[Votos anónimos positivos] - [Votos anónimos negativos]`.
- Total: `[Votos anónimos positivos] + [Votos anónimos negativos]`.

#### [Cantidad de votos de SOes en comparación a votos de otros sitios de SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/821929/votos-publicaciones-y-votos-vistas-paratodos-los-sitios-de-stack-exchange?Anno=2018&Mes=2#resultSets)

Ranking de sitios, ordenados por votos por cantidad de publicaciones, y votos por cantidad de vistas totales, por mes.

> [image]
>   * Captura de febrero 2018 al 11/3/18
>
> Stack Overflow en español se ubica en el final de la lista, #295 de 304 sitios (tiene un ratio de votos por publicaciones de los más bajos de toda la red).

Comment: Qué buena. No sabía sobre el voto anónimo. Acabo de hacer una prueba y con la consola de Chrome vi que se lanza una llamada a _https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/popup/anon-vote/25027?voteTypeId=2_, lo que casa con el tipo de voto que recoges en tu consulta.

Comment: @fedorqui Si te interesa ver los votos anónimos sólo en tus publicaciones:   http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/636822/votos-de-usuarios-no-registrados-por-autor-por-pregunta?IdUsuario=83

Comment: Es una métrica jugosa, con votos muy directos (me funciona/no me funciona, me ayuda/no me ayuda). Me fijé en los resultados para distintos usuarios y en distintos sitios y da buena idea de cuándo una respuesta no satisface demasiado (y las mías no lo hacen demasiado, vistos los resultados). En definitiva, muy útil.

Comment: @fedorqui en mi experiencia, no tiene tanto que ver con la respuesta a la pregunta, sino a lo que esperan según el título que les apareció en Google... Sumado a que son usuarios sin experiencia en SE y más "rabiosos" o "impulsivos"... Buscan código!

Comment: De hecho me da la sensación que las preguntas reciben muchos votos negativos cuando el usuario se encuentra con una pregunta y no una respuesta. Rabia inmediata, votan negativo a menos que la pregunta en sí ya contenga parte de respuesta. Véanse [mis publicaciones en el sitio Spanish](http://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/636822/votos-de-usuarios-no-registrados-por-autor-por-pregunta?IdUsuario=1674) por ejemplo.

Answer (score 4):

## Tráfico

#### [Visitantes únicos por día](https://www.quantcast.com/es.stackoverflow.com?country=GLOBAL#/trafficCard)

Tomado de la cantidad de cookies únicas para la web y de usuarios de la aplicación mobile.
Los valles representan los fines de semana.

> [image]
>   * Captura al 25/5/17

#### [Participación](https://www.quantcast.com/es.stackoverflow.com?country=GLOBAL#/engagementCard)

Segmentación de visitantes únicos por cantidad de visitas al sitio para los últimos 30 días.

> [image]
>   * Captura al 25/5/17

#### [Por país y ciudad](https://www.quantcast.com/es.stackoverflow.com?country=GLOBAL#geographicCard)

Visitantes únicos por país o ciudad.

> [image]
>   * Captura al 25/5/17

Comment: Interesante @Mariano, la mayor cantidad de uv viene de MEX. Lima segunda ciudad :0 excelente!

Comment: Visitantes únicos por país o ciudad, ya no está disponible esta info, es una pena :/

Answer (score 3):

## Estadísticas generales

#### [Site Question Stats](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/226962/site-question-stats#resultSets)

> [image]
>   * Captura al 16/5/17

#### [Cantidad de Preguntas y Respuestas del Último Año](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/6134/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12#graph)

> [image]
>   * Captura al 16/5/17

Comment: Porque esto tiene un -1??

Comment: @jasilva Fui yo, la verdad, es solo cuestión de que las otras me parecen mejores.

Comment: @ArtEze Perdoneme señor mod, no era mi intención, es la costumbre pedir el comentario en los -1

Comment: @jasilva Perdonado.

Answer (score 3):

## Colas de Revisión

#### [Cantidad de publicaciones diarias revisadas por semana](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/681999/colas-de-revision-por-semana-en-stack-overflow-en-espanol-review-queues-by-week?CantMeses=6&VerPrimeras=1&VerEdiciones=1&VerCierre=1&VerBajaCalidad=1&VerTardias=1&VerReapertura=1#graph)

Media por día de tareas de revisión, agrupadas por semana, para los últimos 6 meses.
Cada serie es una cola de revisión diferente.

> [image]
>   * Captura al 7/6/17

#### [Revisiones y demora media diaria por semana](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/809043/revisiones-medias-semanales-cantidad-por-dia-y-demora-review-queues-per-week?CantMeses=12&VerPrimeras=1&VerDemoraPrimeras=1&VerEdiciones=0&VerDemoraEdiciones=0&VerCierre=0&VerDemoraCierre=0&VerBajaCalidad=0&VerDemoraBajaCalidad=0&VerTardias=0&VerDemoraTardias=0&VerReapertura=0&VerDemoraReapertura=0#graph)

Media por día de tareas de revisión, agrupadas por semana, para los últimos N meses.
Permite elegir qué colas y qué demoras medias visualizar.

> [image]
>   * Captura al 19/2/18. Cantidad de revisiones y demora (media diaria) de la cola de Primeras Publicaciones, agrupadas por semana, para los últimos 12 meses.

Answer (score 1):

## Vistas

#### [Promedio de vistas según edad de la pregunta](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/227753/question-age-distribution-and-average-views#graph)

En celeste, la cantidad de preguntas (% del total) que va disminuyendo hacia la derecha a medida que aumenta la edad.
En naranja, la cantidad media de vistas por pregunta (% sobre el máximo), que aumenta con la edad.

> [image]
>
> - Captura al 16/5/17

#### [Perfiles de usuario más vistos](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/681592/perfiles-mas-vistos?Top=50&MinRep=200&MinViews=200#resultSets)

Cuántas veces vieron el perfil de cada usuario.

> [image]
>
> - Captura al 6/6/17

Comment: claramente ser moderador hace que los perfiles sean más sexys :)

Comment: @fedorqui si lo dice el moderador con más vistas de perfil en [spanish.se], superando por más del doble al siguiente usuario, le creo

Comment: ¡Ostras! Ni se me había ocurrido mirarlo. Jajaja y apenas llevo un año como moderador, en breve me silbarán por la calle :D

Comment: Las vistas por reputación en mi caso es demasiado alto debido a las recompensas.

Answer (score 1):

## Preguntas cercanas a eliminarse

#### [Open Question ROOMBA](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/455567/open-question-roomba?CutoffDate=2016-5-16&LastUserAccess=2017-02-16#resultSets)

> [image]
>   * Captura al 19/5/17

#### [Preguntas con respuestas no aceptadas y con puntaje <= 0](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/546331/preguntas-con-respuestas-no-aceptadas-y-con-puntaje-0#resultSets)

> [image]
>   * Captura al 19/5/17