# ¿Cuáles son las reglas para que el icono de revisiones aparezca en naranja?

Tags: soporte, barra-superior, colas-de-revisión

En la barra superior, cada tanto, el indicador de las colas de revisión aparece resaltado en naranja.

[image: barra superior con revisiones en naranja]

En [“posts awaiting review” orange counter is way off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653/5290909) explican que para Stack Overflow en inglés es 1 hora sin revisar y 513 en cola (mediana por hora/2 aprox), pero claramente no es nuestro caso.

---

¿Cuáles son las reglas para que aparezca resaltado en el sitio principal y en Meta?

Comment: Sería interesante saber cuál es la mediana por hora. A mí por ejemplo ahora me sale en naranja y hay apenas dos elementos en total en las colas que pudo revisar.

Comment: @fedorqui actualmente hay 4 (+ 3 de cierre) para revisar (se ve en una ventana de incógnito). Pero antes que seguir mirando minuto a minuto, esperaba que pudieran responder qué valor le configuraron ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui Generé un gráfico en SEDE para revisiones y lo publiqué en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2145/127

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se lo consulté a Shog9 en los comentarios de la respuesta que mencionaste. Me indica ahora que en [Algorithm for review icon highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296946/209901) ha dado una explicación al tema.

Traduzcámosla:

> Tal y comenté [aquí](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653) se destaca en naranja el icono de revisones en Stack Overflow *si*...
>
> - No has apretado el botón de revisión en la barra superior, revisado ninguna publicación, o visitado `/review` durante algún tiempo (actualmente 60 minutos) *y*...
> - ... Hay más de un número trivial de tareas pendientes (ajusté este valor manualmente a aproximadamente la mitad de la media de tareas pendientes en una hora dada - esto está sujeto a cambio en cualquier momento, pues el número en el que se basa ha estado desperdigado a medida que hemos ido haciendo cambios en la barra superior y los criterios de revisión en los últimos meses. El valor por defecto es 3, pero está definido en 513 en SO y 30 en SOru).

Por tanto, en Stack Overflow tenemos el valor por defecto 3, así que si hay al menos este número de tareas pendientes y se cumple el primer criterio, se ilumina el botón.

- Nota: el número de tareas pendientes no incluye a la cola de cierre de preguntas.

Comment: Actualmente, la [mediana por hora para el último mes](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/682426/mediana-de-tareas-de-revision-por-hora-en-stack-overflow-en-espanol-median-revie?CantDias=30) es **4.21**. Esto es la mediana de **cantidad de tareas**, no la mediana de activas por hora (que es el número utilizado y que no se puede obtener de SEDE)