# ¡Alarma ROJA! ¡Alarma ROJA! ¿Qué quieren decir los puntos rojos en el icono de revisión?

Tags: soporte, barra-superior, colas-de-revisión

Tengo unos puntos de alarma roja en la parte superior de la página.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Empiezo a correr en círculos mientras agito histéricamente los brazos y grito FUEGO, FUEGO?

Más en serio, ¿qué significa? ¿Hay otros colores?

Comment: es lo mas molesto que vi hasta ahora. sobre todo cuando la cola explota, y uno ya paso por esa.. sigo apretando como tonto a ver si aparece algo nuevo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Es un indicador de que hay revisiones pendientes en un número mayor a la media histórica. En concreto, se pone rojo cuando el valor está en el percentil 90 y hace al menos una hora desde que apretaste el icono por última vez.

Básicamente, es un recordatorio de que hay tareas de revisión por hacer cuando estas se han acumulado más de lo normal.

También verás que en ocasiones (las más) se iluminará con un color grisáceo. Eso ocurre cuando hay al menos un elemento en la cola, pero menos de los necesarios para encender el colorcito rojo.

Los detalles están explicados (en inglés) en [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/209901), que está actualmente en modo de prueba:

```
Queue                 Default
-----          --------------  
Close                      20
Reopen                      5
Low Quality                 4
Suggested Edits             3
First Posts                10
Late Answers                6
Help (Stack Overflow)     150
Triage (Stack Overflow)   100
```

Relacionado a lo comentado en [¿Cuáles son las reglas para que el icono de revisiones aparezca en naranja?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2144/83).