# Me avisa de sugerencias de edición de wikis de etiqueta pese a que no puedo acceder a ellas

Tags: bug, colas-de-revisión, privilegios

Desde hace horas, cada vez que entro en el sitio observo que el sistema me indica que hay ediciones sugeridas pendientes:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, cuando entro en [/revisar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) observo un precioso 0 al lado de *Ediciones sugeridas*.

Lo primero que pensé es: [¿será culpa de la caché?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) Pero no, esta vez no, pues sí hay sugerencias pendientes: haciendo alguna investigación llegué a ver que unas cuantas sugerencias para editar wikis de etiqueta (por ejemplo, [esta de elecciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/277)). Como mi reputación no llega a los 5 000 puntos, no puedo acceder al privilegio [Aprobación de wikis de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

El bug está en que me indica que hay revisiones pendientes cuando yo no puedo acceder a ellas. En particular, me avisa de sugerencias de edición de páginas wiki de etiquetas.

El [CM Jon Ericson comenta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305893/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil#comment998800_305893):

> That's a bug. We didn't think about/remember that approving tag wiki edits is at a different privilege level from approving post suggested edits. Unfortunately, I don't think this won't be an easy bug to fix without changing quite a bit of logic on the backend. But I'll check with a developer who knows better than I do. Under normal situations, this ought to be a fairly rare problem. (For clarity, SOes uses the [danger indicator system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/209901), not this one. It's a bug for both.)

Comment: A mi me suena que esto estaba reportado,incluso no se si aqui mismo....

Comment: @Pikoh tienes razón, en [¿Por qué me aparecen tareas pendientes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/837/83) se habló de ello. Sin embargo, al ser algo de hace dos años y haber cambiado todo, pensé que era un nuevo bug ¿? No sé.

Comment: Yo creo que es lo mismo, que sigue igual :) De todas maneras, me suena algo mas reciente, creo que de @gbianchi. A ver si lo encuentro

Comment: Tal vez me refería a esta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2856/15301, pero me sonaba otra hablando precisamente de que seguia marcando en rojo aunque personalmente no tuvieras nada. O tal vez fuera en el chat...

Comment: @Pikoh pues es que es raro porque teóricamente sí estaba corregido este tema. Así lo detalla el CM Jon Ericson en la publicación que enlazo al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Pues será otra de esas cosas que mutan y se estropean misteriosamente, como las traducciones.. :)

Comment: @Mariano entiendo, y no tengo problema en marcar como duplicado. Lo que me deja con la mosca tras la oreja es que Jon Ericson había dicho que esto ya no sucedía.

Comment: yo no lo puse en meta, o estaba dup y la borre.. pero me queje de eso en algun lado.. tal vez en el chat?

Comment: Ya vi tu comentario en MSE... retiro el voto, y esperemos a la respuesta de Jon Ericson para actualizar la respuesta (cerrando la de Konami como duplicado de esta)

Comment: @Mariano de hecho incluso ahora me sale, que [solamente hay una](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/273).

Comment: @fedorqui (parece que no estoy contando bien) hay 3 al menos: [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/278), la que mencionaste y [otra](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/271) (que habría que rechazar, y yo me equivoqué y voté por aprobar).

Comment: @Mariano ah vale, ¿tantas? Yo solamente conté las que supe encontrar (mi método fue rápido, pero bastante fiable: mirar en [tus sugerencias](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) y contar cuántas constaban como _edición pendiente_ :P

Comment: De hecho, agregando al caso, también me muestra el icono rojo a mí (que no puedo revisar mis propias sugerencias)... simplemente se cuenta el total por cola

Comment: @Mariano confirmado: es un bug porque no tuvieron en cuenta este caso límite de la cola de sugerencias de edición, que puede tener elementos no revisables según la reputación. Véase el [comentario completo de Jon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305893/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil#comment998800_305893), donde comenta que lo hablará con un dev, pero que al ser algo relativamente puntual será difícil que se solucione.

Comment: @fedorqui me dejaste boquiabierto. Jamás pensé que lo fuese a considerar un bug. Aplaudo tu insistencia para llegar al fondo de la cuestión... Y viene bien saber que estábamos leyendo de la publicación equivocada, que en realidad es [*How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/304899)