# ¿Por qué me marca como que la cola de revisión está saturada y al mismo tiempo que está limpia?

Tags: discusión, colas-de-revisión, barra-superior

Como una imagen vale más que mil palabras...

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar, me marca la cola de Ediciones sugeridas con un círculo rojo que entiendo que se supone que está saturada esa cola de revisión en particular.

Pero, por el contrario, si me meto en la cola de revisión, me dice **¡Esta cola ha sido limpiada!**.

Supongo que será porque ya he revisado todas las **Ediciones sugeridas** y, por lo tanto, mi cola de revisión particular está limpia aunque en la global haya todavía bastantes preguntas sin cerrar para esa categoría concreta.

De todas formas, ¿no lo veis un poco incoherente? ¿Podría tratarse de una especie de bug?

Comment: Sí, es exactamente eso: son revisiones pendientes que no tenés acceso a revisar, ya sea por ser el autor de una sugerencia, porque ya la revisaste o (no es tu caso) por no tener el privilegio para revisar sugerencias en wikis de etiqueta. Lamentablemente es por diseño (no es un bug). Es porque sino la consulta sobre cada página consume demasiados recursos... PD: hay un duplicado, no me acuerdo cuál era

Comment: @Mariano no es el mismo caso que reporté yo de [Me avisa de sugerencias de edición de wikis de etiqueta pese a que no puedo acceder a ellas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3187/83), pues Francisco tiene reputación suficiente para revisar las sugerencias de revisión de etiqueta wiki ([son 5000](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)). Probablemente sea un caso de caching, como el que se mencionaba en [¿Por qué me aparecen tareas pendientes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/837/83) y que supuestamente estaba corregido.

Comment: @fedorqui no es el mismo caso que tu reporte, solamente listé el motivo (diciendo "*no es tu caso*"). Y, sí, creo que es duplicada de la de Konami... No es un problema de cacheo, sino de que hay tareas pendientes que no puede revisar. Como te respondió Jon, esto nunca se modificó en SOes. La lógica que se usa actualmente es: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/304899 (no se excluyen las ya revisadas).

Comment: @Mariano disculpa, leí mal tu comentario inicial.

Comment: @fedorqui al contrario, si nunca hubiésemos entrado en este tipo de comentarios, no sabríamos cuál es la lógica actual ni qué pasa con wikis. ;-)

Comment: @Mariano La he marcado como duplicada ya que supongo que será por la suposición que tenía en mente y era en relación a que ya había revisado dichas colas de revisión pero en cuanto a valores generales todavía no habían sido revisadas del todo.

Comment: Es que es más que una suposición @Fran, es lo nos que pasa *todo* el tiempo a quienes revisamos bastante, estoy seguro de que es el motivo... Pero está bien verlo más allá de los supuestos, acá va el caso: en el momento en que publicaste esta pregunta, ya habías revisado https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/89097 y faltaba aún el 2do revisor, por lo que estaba pendiente para el sitio, pero no para tu usuario.

Comment: @Mariano Me encanta la capacidad que tienes para realizar estadísticas/recopilar información rápidamente. Realmente fascinante. De nuevo, gracias :)

Comment: jaja, tampoco tanto! Solamente fui a ver tus revisiones en https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16108/francisco-romero?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=3, busqué una que esté un poco antes de esta pregunta y la abrí para ver si el 2do revisor vino más tarde... O más rápido para quienes tenemos el privilegio, buscando tu nombre en el historial de ediciones sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history

Comment: @Mariano No sabía de la existencia de la primera pestaña xD Y de la segunda, no veo ningún buscador que te permita buscar por nombre, no?

Comment: No, no... fui a la 3ra página, que es donde coincidía la fecha, y mirando a ojo lo encontré (o Ctrl + F)... pero se encuentra muy fácil siendo reciente.