# ¿Se pueden ver las estadísticas de Stackoverflow en español?

Tags: discusión, data-explorer, estadísticas

Según el artículo [The decline of Stack Overflow: *How trolls have taken over your favorite programming Q&A site*](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) cuyo título en castellano sería: El declive de Stackoverflow: *Como los trolls se han apoderado de su sitio favorito de preguntas y respuestas sobre programación*, las estadísticas de Stackoverflow (supongo que en inglés), eran aproximadamente las siguientes para el año 2015:

- Usuarios registrados: 4,000,000
- Preguntas: 10,000,000 (sin contar preguntas y usuarios borrados).

Según el mismo sitio, en 2013 un estudio reveló lo siguiente:

- Usuarios que han formulado solamente una pregunta: 77%
- Usuarios que han respondido solamente a una pregunta: 65%
- Usuarios que han respondido a más de 5 preguntas: 8%

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de conocer las estadísticas de Stackoverflow en español con respecto a una fecha reciente.

Comment: [Data Explorer de Stack Exchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/) es tu amigo :)

Comment: lo ha hecho Mariano en [Métricas interesantes para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1998/6635)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>[image: Métricas]</kbd>
<sup><sub>* Captura de métricas actualizadas al 18/7/17 0:58 UTC</sub></sup>

Lo generé con un query en SEDE que publiqué en http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/699947 y donde se pueden consultar los datos actuales (los datos en SEDE se actualizan cada domingo aproximadamente a las 3:00 UTC).

Más métricas referidas a SOes: [Métricas interesantes para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1998/127).