# ¿Cuál es el tiempo promedio de la atención de las diferentes colas, en particular la edición de etiquetas?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas, ediciones-sugeridas, colas-de-revisión

Entiendo que hay un límite de 5 ediciones sugeridas pendientes para usuarios con *< 2k* de reputación.

Frente a este escenario me ha surgido la pregunta, ¿En qué tiempo atenderán mis revisiones para poder seguir revisando y aportando material valioso al sitio? Siento que esto es una limitante y de alguna manera frena la dinámica de colaboración.

Comment: los fines de semana la limpieza de las colas es mas lenta... paciencia, los que aprueban son colaboradores igual q vos..

Comment: Puedes [editar tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4673/edit) incluyendo el enlace de tu edición sugerida. Al revisar la cola de ediciones sugeridas no me apareció ninguna tuya.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @gbianchi, esta fue mi percepcion y mi obligacion era comunicarla, ese es el sentido de la comunidad. ArtEze - gracias por la sugerencia, sin embargo ya mis ediciones sugeridas fueron atendidas. Gracias a todos!

Comment: Las estuve mirando.. fijate los comentarios donde los deje..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente depende mucho del día de la semana y el momento del año. Puede resultarte útil la consulta [Median time to review tag wiki edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/851198/median-time-to-review-tag-wiki-edits), que a mí me da como resultado 769 (entiendo que minutos, luego 12 horas; aunque me parece que suele ser más).

También es práctico leer esta publicación de Mariano en [Métricas interesantes para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1998/83):

> #### [Cantidad de publicaciones diarias revisadas por semana](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/681999/colas-de-revision-por-semana-en-stack-overflow-en-espanol-review-queues-by-week?CantMeses=6&VerPrimeras=1&VerEdiciones=1&VerCierre=1&VerBajaCalidad=1&VerTardias=1&VerReapertura=1#graph)
>
> Media por día de tareas de revisión, agrupadas por semana, para los
>   últimos 6 meses.   Cada serie es una cola de revisión diferente.
>
> > [image]
> >     * Captura al 7/6/17
>
> #### [Revisiones y demora media diaria por semana](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/809043/revisiones-medias-semanales-cantidad-por-dia-y-demora-review-queues-per-week?CantMeses=12&VerPrimeras=1&VerDemoraPrimeras=1&VerEdiciones=0&VerDemoraEdiciones=0&VerCierre=0&VerDemoraCierre=0&VerBajaCalidad=0&VerDemoraBajaCalidad=0&VerTardias=0&VerDemoraTardias=0&VerReapertura=0&VerDemoraReapertura=0#graph)
>
> Media por día de tareas de revisión, agrupadas por semana, para los
>   últimos N meses.   Permite elegir qué colas y qué demoras medias
>   visualizar.
>
> > [image]
> >     * Captura al 19/2/18. Cantidad de revisiones y demora (media diaria) de la cola de Primeras Publicaciones, agrupadas por semana, para los
> >     últimos 12 meses.

---

En cuanto a tus ediciones pendientes, las encontré buceando en la [actividad de tu perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/135785/jorge-beltran?tab=activity). En ella veo que había distintas sugerencias de edición en extractos y wikis de etiqueta, y creo que ahora ya están casi todas resueltas. Por lo general, debe tenerse en cuenta que:

- Gestionar sugerencias de edición a una publicación requiere una reputación de 2000 ([Privilegios > Editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)), pero
- Gestionar sugerencias de edición a una etiqueta requiere de 5000 ([Privilegios > Aprobación de wikis de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits))

Por tanto, mucha menos gente puede revisar el tipo de sugerencias que enviaste (73 contra 213, según las [ligas de reputación](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/alltime/es-stackoverflow/2015-12-01/83#83)).

---

Finalmente, verás que algunas de tus sugerencias han sido rechazadas, especialmente en las de edición de extractos. El motivo esgrimido es el de:

> La mera definición de qué es una [etiqueta] raramente sirve de ayuda para aquellos que la usan, a no ser que el propio nombre de la etiqueta sea ambiguo. El resumen debería describir por qué y cuándo debería usarse esta. [Consulta el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) para más información.

Lee con detenimiento esa información. Y, por supuesto, ¡gracias por hacer mejor este sitio!