# ¿Pondrán el botón aplausos en SOes?

Tags: característica-nueva, respuesta

Veo en *StackOverflow en inglés* un botón para aplaudir una respuesta, cosa que me pareció bastante bueno.

Muestro una captura de pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de respuesta en SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62657938/ Hay tres aplausos.

Ejemplo de respuesta en SOes: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/366122/ Aquí no está el botón de aplausos.

Al tocar en el botón de aplausos, cambiaría el 3 por un 4... Estos no le dan reputación, solo es para indicar que te gustó la respuesta.

¿Pondrán esta característica en SOes? ¿Hay planes para hacerlo? ¿Existe alguna estimación de una fecha concreta?

Comment: Los aplausos en SO se utilizan para dar las gracias y la forma de decir gracias en SOes, es votando a favor.

Comment: @Shassain Entiendo, pero hay bastante diferencia, ese botón puede servir, por ejemplo, para que no cambie el lugar en la ordenación por votos, o al buscar una respuesta por una cantidad exacta de votos y que se siga manteniendo.

Comment: espero que no... semejante invento parece ir muy en contra de lo que se supone que es SO. Por suerte, la presentación de [la publicación que lo presentó](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398367/1983854) tuvo (de momento) un recibimiento bastante demoledor, con puntuación de menos de -1000 y [la siguiente para justificarlo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398909/1983854) ya va por -278

Comment: sobretodo que en SOes parece que la gente no puntúa las preguntas (al menos ni de cerca a lo que lo hacen en SO), parecería un paso hacia atrás

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Me parece que lo del recibimiento "demoledor" es poco significativo ya que es claro que la característica en cuestión nada tiene ver  con los usuarios que usan Meta.. Según entiendo va dirigida a los que rara vez o poco usan el sitio y que aún menos usan Meta.

Comment: @Rubén tienes razón en cuanto al público _utilizador_, si bien lo pueden ver todos los usuarios. De todos modos, el público _receptor_ es el que se ha mostrado de forma masiva en contra. Yo mismo estoy en contra: no me desagrada recibir comentarios de "gracias"; al contrario, los agradezco y, por contra, estos aplausos no sé ni cuándo me llegan y me parecen muy fríos. Además, el voto para usuarios no registrados ya se está guardando, como bien [nos descubrió](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2000/83) el bueno de Mariano.

Comment: Espero que no se me mal interprete, yo no me estoy manifestando en este espacio ni a favor ni en contra de la característica en cuestión sólo hablo de la perspectivas sobre las magnitudes. Según entiendo del público receptor sólo una pequeña parte (score ~ -1k Vs 30m respuestas ) ha manifestado su postura ya sea votando y/o publicando comentarios en Meta.

Comment: En cuanto al 30m respuestas no es el mejor número pero no quiero invertir tiempo en este momento en ver cuantos usuarios ha recibido un "gracias" por medio de esta característica, ya lo informarán cuando publiquen los resultados en análisis de los datos recopilados durante la prueba.

Comment: @Rubén sí, sí, mi beligerancia es hacia esta funcionalidad, nada en contra tuya :) Lo de la representatividad de Meta ha sido un tema potente últimamente. SE se atrevió a desdeñar su utilidad, hasta que [descubrieron que la gente de Meta es la que sustenta el invento](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343839/209901) y dieron marcha atrás, al menos en parte. Veremos en qué queda esto.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' De acuerdo con Meta es pieza fundamental y como tal sería bueno que se usara mejor. Yo ví como avance que el CEO abriera hilos en Meta para sus artículos del blog. Me hubiese gustado que lo mismo hubieran hecho cuando anunciaron en Twitter los planes sobre las reacciones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aún no es definitivo que el botón de *reacciones* se mantenga en SO por lo que no sabemos si tendremos eso en SOes.

El post oficial mas reciente habla sobre la validación de los datos que se está obtiendo durante la prueba de esta caracterísica. - > [Data validation & background for the Thank You Reaction feature test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398909/1595451). En este post se menciona que la característica en cuestión se retirará el día 17 de julio.